What are the chances of getting a second postdoc after two years of unemployment gap?
I have a 2 years of employment gap after my one year long first postdoc (Biochemistry). I left it because I did not like the lab. And after that I was unsure what to do (it was almost traumatising to move to another country and then leave without a plan within a year). I decided not to persue research career further. I did a course in scietific writing and did a freelance job during this time. But now I miss being in the lab. I want to continue doing research. What are my chances to get a postdoc after a 2 years of gap and that my postdoc supervisor (well known) will not give me a reference. I have good publications and reference from my Phd supervisor and others. Do I stand a chance? And how do I adrees it in my CV?

Your chances are better if you make application. But this depends too much on what we don't and can't know to make any prediction.

Promote the experience and positive contributions that you will bring to a position. Do not dwell on what you believe you are missing.
